# How to use core.async in place of callbacks?

Tags: node.js, callback, clojurescript, core.async

I'm using core.async on ClojureScript to avoid using node.js callbacks. The problem is that I'm hitting the 1024 pending messages limit.

To avoid it, I would need to send all messages to channels inside the same `go` block. But this is not really possible on core.async because an anonymous function nullifies the effect of `go`, so I can't do this:

```clj
(go
  (. socket on "data" #(>! chan %)))
```

So, is there a way to get around this limitation?

Comment: I just added an appropriate language hint. When tagging with both clojurescript and node.js or javascript please use the hint to ensure the syntax highlighter works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate the error, we can "simulate" a kind of callback:

```
(let [callback (atom nil)
      on-data (fn [fun]
                (reset! callback fun))
      chan (async/chan)]
```

If we try to add a callback with `(on-data #(async/go (async/put! chan %)))`, it'll blow the limit. Also, as we're using `async/go`, it'll cause the messages inside the channel to be out of order.

The only way I found out to fix this is to create an infinite list of `promise-chan` inside an `atom` and every callback will pick up the first element, publish a message, and remove the first for the list. Then, we can have a `doseq` inside a `go` block that'll publish messages for us:

```
(let [inf-list (atom (map (fn [_] (async/promise-chan)) (range)))]
  ; We need to iterate over inf-list before anything
  (let [lst @inf-list]
    (async/go
     (doseq [c lst]
       (async/>! chan (async/<! c)))))

  (on-data #(do
              (async/put! (first @inf-list) %)
              (swap! inf-list rest))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand why it has to be in the same go block. Normally, you would just do:

```clj
(. socket on "data" #(go (put! chan %)))
```

and then process the chan in another go block

Comment: This fails when there's too much backpressure with the error `AssertionError Assert failed: No more than 1024 pending puts are allowed`

Comment: In fact, the code above would not throw an exception because it's inside a `go` block. But if you wrap `put!` around a `(try... (catch Throwable t ...))` You'll see the error